# Управление ресурсами

Tags: c++, указатели, память, ресурсы

Возник такой вопрос, можно ли выделить некое пространство памяти, под разные типы данных, вот например я выделяю память под указатель из (heap), в размере 100мб, а далее я уже в этом пространстве (заранее знаю что не выйду за его пределы), буду подгружать другие данные, например есть загрузчик, который загружает саму инфу о карте, тайлы, звуки, анимацию, но под эти данные тоже выделяется память, тоже из (heap) и известно что она будет выделяться в свободном пространстве.
Вот в чем собственно вопрос:

1) Можно ли поместить все эти данные в выделенную память (100мб).

2) Если я освобожу эти 100мб из того "главного" указателя, то будет ли выделяться та память которая была выделена например для текстур, то есть именно освобождения указателя на эту текстуру не происходило, зато было высвобождена вся память.

В итоге пришел к такому вот способу:

```
void *bigData = new char[sizeof(char)*1024];

char myNewData = '5';

memcpy((&bigData + sizeof(char)*8), &myNewData, sizeof(char));

cout << "data val: " << myNewData << endl;
cout << "start pos: " << &bigData << endl;
cout << "end pos: " << &bigData + (sizeof(char)*1024) << endl;
cout << "data in: " << &bigData + sizeof(char)*8 << endl;
cout << "data int copy block: " << *reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bigData + sizeof(char)*8) << endl;

delete [] bigData;
```

Comment: Можно, не вопрос. Как сделаете - так и будет. Помещайте ваши данные в эту память - они и будут в нее помещаться. Это все ваша задача.

Comment: @AnT а как это можно сделать? есть предположение но оно весьма спорное, хотелось бы увидеть небольшой пример.

Comment: Переопределите операторы new и delete. Это все можно, но работа достаточно сложная и неблагодарная - ведь вам нужно по сути **писать свой менеджер памяти**. Что вы хотите при этом выиграть?

Comment: @Harry чтобы не следить самому за памятью, и в любом случае точно знать что нет не освобожденной памяти.

Comment: Чтобы не следить самому за памятью, для начала освойте умные указатели. А также гуглите "пул объектов" - object pool.

Comment: Неосвобожденной как раз будет полно :) - ваш пул. А вот как вы потом внутри него будете выделять-освобождать, вы не задумывались?

Comment: @eSkry: Вы задаете какой-то слушком неконкретный вопрос, который звучит как  "как поместить данные в память?".

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно, выделяемую память можно представлять как линейную последовательность подряд идущих байт. Т.е. ответ на Ваш первый вопрос, можно ли выделив память первый раз, дальше использовать её куски отдельно в своих целях, записывая туда что угодно разных типов - то да, можно. Главное следить за границами, что бы данные не вылезали за пределы массива и не налазили друг на друга.

Ответ на второй вопрос - если вы освободите эту память из главного указателя, то остальные указатели будут теперь указыватьна "зомби" обьекты и память. Фактически Ваши данные из памяти не исчезнут, но сама эта память станет доступна для записи и для редактирования из вне, так что обьекты скорее всего через неторое количество времени будут повреждены и в них может появиться разный мусор, либо полностью испортив обьект, либо частично. Из-за этого могут возникать сбои в Вашей программе, поэтому стоит внимательно следить за тем, что Вы освобождаете.